# Positioning elements in a grid

Tags: html, css

You need to have several 200px wide DIVs (.item) inside a 620px wide DIV (.container).

- The .container DIV should fit 3 .item DIVs in a row.
- The .item DIVs should be exactly 10px away from each other.
- There should be no space between the border of the .container DIV and the .item DIVs immediately next to it.

See the figure bellow for a better understanding.

How would you achieve it - margins, a table...?

[image]

Comment: Can you give every third item an additional class?

Comment: I think it is important to know what is around your element (the 620px dic) and how you want this element to interact with his neighbors, because doing what you want could differ if you require position: absolute or position: relative, etc.

Comment: @polarblau, yes, that would be an option, but if you do that you should probably need another class for the items in the first (or last) row that will define specific `padding-bottom` (or `padding-top` for the last row)

Comment: @Shaun Hare, yes, I'd be interested in seeing a CSS3 approach.

Comment: Are you using a float structure with a random number of item divs or will the structure of this particular table be static?

Comment: @Joel Etherton, it should work with any number of items.

Comment: Happy with using css3 ? :nth-child selector or nth-of-type Anna debenham who rocks did this http://maban.co.uk/29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try the following, but this way you will have to add a 'mask', but no need for css3, nor adding/removing classes depending on where the item is (in other words, no need for any type of scripts, just pure html/css):

HTML:

```
<div class='mask'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='item'></div>
        <div class='item'></div>
        <div class='item'></div>
        <div class='item'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .mask{border:10px solid #ddd;width:620px;overflow:hidden}
 .container{width:630px;background-color:#333;margin-top:-10px;overflow:hidden;float:left}
 .item{float:left;margin-right:10px;width:200px;height:100px;background-color:#4a6b82;margin-top:10px}
```

Try here : [Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/a3PnJ/)

Comment: That's a very interesting approach. Thanks for the Demo!

Comment: Though it doesn't require 'scripting' (I assume you mean server-side scripting here), this design can be a bit too rigid: when the contents of an item exceed the box, the design is broken: http://www.jsfiddle.net/a3PnJ/8/. Also, much more CSS here than needed (see my example below), I would say adding an extra class each third item is justified, and semantically correct.

Comment: @Peter Kruithof, I like your approach. In fact I've been using it a lot. I find Dan's approach interesting because it seems very clean and is one I haven't seen.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a table. Unless it's tabular data, that is.

Float each div, give it the desired width and margin, and make sure the last div in the row doesn't have this margin. You can accomplish this using a class, or using the css `:nth-child(3)` pseudo selector. Because of the lack of support for this selector I would recommend a class for it.

One more thing: this works fine if all div's have equal heights. If they don't, you may encounter some weird positioning across various browsers. The best way to work around this is to put the three div's of each row in a row div.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"/>
    <div class="item"/>
    <div class="item last"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"/>
    <div class="item"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item { float: left; width: 200px; margin-right: 10px; }
.last { margin-right: 0; }
```

Comment: How about the margins between the rows?

Comment: @steweb, sure, but that would require another class. Isn't that too complicated for a simple task such as placing items in a grid?

Comment: Again, same approach. For last row, margin-bottom:0; and for others margin-bottom:10px

Comment: @Emanuil no there's no need of another class. You just have to set margin-bottom to each row, except for the last one (i.e. .container:last-child{margin-bottom:none})

Comment: The CSS authors implemented just the feature for users that would find specifying a different last margin 'too complicated': collapsing margins. See this article: http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/. IMHO, this is not complicated stuff at all.